# Script to enter user credentials automatically

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, iframe

I have an application which has an iframe pointing to a specific web site. 
When any user logs into this application and when the default jsp loads(which contains the iframe)**,**  I would like to enter the username and password and make the login in the web site, which is in the iframe.  Can anyone help me with the script which makes this possible ?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the site in the iframe is from another origin (read: domain), you will not be able to do that. Browser security prevents you from accessing documents from a different origin.

Comment: @Ajj: Unless you can get some code of your own on the destination site you'd have to break browser security to do it, which you don't want to do.